# How To apply Animations using React Router when going from one route to another?

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-router-dom

Suppose I have made some routes in the navigation component and when I click them the route changes and they navigate me to another component. Now if I want to apply some animations when navigating from one route to another, how can I do it when I am using react-router dom??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are few packages available. You can explore [React Router's Animated Transition](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/animated-transitions) OR another most used package [framer-motion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/framer-motion).